# Can't use operator<< as a method?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I used to define operator<< as a function, like I did with most of my operators.

```
class MyClass {
    int myAttribute;

public :

    MyClass(int attr):
        myAttribute(attr){}

    int getter() {return myAttribute;}
};

MyClass operator+(MyClass mc1, MyClass mc2)
{
    MyClass mc(mc1.getter()+mc2.getter());
    return mc;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &stream, MyClass mc)
{
    stream << mc.getter();
    return stream;
}
```

All this works well but I was told that I could define it as a method. I removed the definitions of operator+ and operator<< and I got no problem with operator+

```
MyClass MyClass::operator+(MyClass mc1)
{
    MyClass mc(mc1.getter()+myAttribute);
    return mc;
}
```

but it's doesn't work with operator<<

```
std::ostream& MyClass::operator<< (std::ostream &stream)
{
    stream << myAttribute;
    return stream;
}
```

I get the error :

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'MyClass')
```

What do I miss ?

Comment: Unfortunately, [the relevant answer in the dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34954015/434551) is way down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `std::ostream& MyClass::operator<< (std::ostream &stream)` is used when you write `MyClass m; m << std::cout;`. That is not what you intended.

If you add `std::ostream &std::ostream::operator<<(const MyClass &m)` then that would work for `MyClass m; std::cout << m;`, but it requires you to change the standard headers, which you cannot, so the non-member version is the only viable option.

Note that the non-member version is not part of `MyClass` and therefore cannot access `private` members of `MyClass`. If you need that you can add `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &stream, const MyClass &mc);` to `MyClass` to make that possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<<` must be a non-member function. You cannot make it a "method" if you want to use it with `std::cout` on the left-hand side and your own class on the right-hand side.

But you can declare the `operator<<` as a friend if it needs access to `private` data of `MyClass`.

Comment: @GoverNator: The word "method" doesn't really exist in C++. The OP used it as a synonym for what is correctly called "member function".

Comment: *thats a rule in C++.*?? Not really. After all, `ostream` has some of them as member functions.

Comment: @RSahu: OK, what about *"It's a rule in C++ that you have to make `operator<<` a non-member function if it takes a right-hand side argument of another class"*?

Comment: @RSahu: Better now?

Comment: it is definitely better :)